# If $K$ is not perfect then there are inseparable irreducible polynomials (Dummit & Foote, P549 )

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

> If $K$ is not perfect then there are inseparable irreducible polynomials.

This is not obvious to me at all. I have tried to reduce the question to

> If $K$ is not perfect then there exist irreducible polynomial $p(x)$ such that it is not coprime with $D_xp(x)$.

Since $p(x)$ is irreducible, $p(x)$ must be the common factor. But $D_x p(x)$ has lower degree, hence $D_xp(x)=0$. So $p(x) = q(x^p)$. So now I want to show

> If $\exists k \in K$ that $\forall \hat k \in K, k \neq \hat k^p$, then there exist irreducible polynomial $p(x)$ such that it can be written as $p(x) = q(x^p)$.

Then I am stuck..

Comment: Did you think of $P=x^p-k$? (Calling the polynomial $p$ is not such a great idea.)

Comment: Not being perfect means that some algebraic extension is not separable, so there is an element such that the simple extension over it is not separable, so there is your polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider $K=\mathbb{F}_2(u)$ and $uT^2-1$. See if you can generalize.

Comment: What is $T$? Thanks Alex.

Comment: @1LiterTears An indeterminate, this is a polynomial in $K[T]$.